# How to go up to parent Activity that need to be started with extras data?

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have an app which `Activity A` will show a post and also its comments. If I click one of the comment, it will go to `Activity B`. So, `Activity B` will show comment and also replies for that comment. Up until now, I don't have a problem. I just need to set parent `Activity` for `Activity B` to `Activity A` in `manifest.xml`.

Now, I also have `Activity X` which will show user profile and also all of their posts and comments. If I click a comment, it will go to `Activity B`. But, if I click up button, it will go back to `Activity X`. How to make it go back to `Activity A`?

By the way, to start `Activity A`, I need to supply extra data which contains the ID for that post and for every comments, they also have an ID of their post ID.

Is it possible to do the following in `Activity B`?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // if come from Activity A:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            // else
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
                intent.putLong("ID", comment.getPostId());
                startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Or should I use something like `TaskStackBuilder` to start `Activity B` from `Activity X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to do this. My favorite is to pass the necessary information to the `Intent` something like this with your setup

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra(CALLER_ACTIVITY);
  if (caller.equals(ActivityA.class.getName())) {
      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      return; // dont need to do anything
  } else if (caller.equals(ActivityX.class.getName())) {
      intent.setClass(this, ActivityA.class);
  }
  intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras()); // if more info needed
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
```

Another approach would be to use `getCallingActivity`, but this only works if you started the Activity with `startActivityForResult()`.
If you use `AppCompat` you can get the caller by using [AppCompat.getReferrer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#getReferrer(android.app.Activity))

The behaviour might change of the above options, that's why it's a good idea to use the Intent way.

You would start the `ActivityB` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityB.CALLER_ACTIVITY, this.getClass().getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You might consider changing the .equals call order to `ActivityA.class.getName().equals(caller)` to avoid potential NPEs if caller was not set. (Or maybe not, because it could mask developer errors)