# Activity.finish unless there is nothing behind

Tags: android, android-activity

in whatsapp when you are in a chat and go back it closes the chat leaving you at the home screen scrolled to where you were.  However if you got to the chat through a notification and there is no home screen then it creates a new one.  How do they do this?

I was thinking some sort of ifHasBackStack, but was wondering if there is a cleaner way and if not what is the best way to find the backstack size

It appears in trying to be more clear in my question i made it slightly different to the actual use case, however this was a mistake as the answer changes now.

The actual use case is i want apps to be able to share items to my app from their gallery (or other image apps).  If the user gets an image from inside the app, i can use activity.finish() on the final part of the posting an image section and it works great, however if i use activity.finish() if they get to my app from another app eg gallery, then i want to take them to my home screen.

Sorry for the confusion caused!

Comment: With Intents e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194750/4467208

Comment: i dont see how that helps.  How do you use intents to go back where you were unless there is no backstack?

Comment: You check the extras of the Intent. You can put anything there and since Notification uses PendingIntent

Comment: i dont think you are understanding the question (or possibly i am not understanding your answer), my problem is this.

I have activity A, list of messages, I scroll down and click on a message to open a message.  Activity B opens.  I close activity B using the activity.close() and activity A comes back scrolled down to where it was.  However if i get to activity B through a notification then when i click the back button the app closes it doesnt go back to activity A

Comment: @AdamKatz: you need to save information in the pending intent. or you can use the approach I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to achieve what you are asking.

One very trivial approach is that once clicked on the notification, launch the home screen and read the intent data. get the specific user/chat id. and based on that user will be navigated to that chat thread. And when user will click on back button, the home screen will be already there.

There are some different approaches to achieve this behavior

Comment: thanks, someone privated me this link so I am going to go through it in detail, if i go with your advice ill give it the green tick if i find a better way then i will make a new answer

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 1):

I did the same in my project when showing notification

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(YourActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
// Define notification builder 
// .....
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.CHATS_NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

**Updated: (If you want to open specific activity from other app)**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your.app.YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <!-- Add below intent filter if you want to enable image sharing -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks my problem is, is that i am trying to do it from the gallery and not from a notification - i never included that in my original description

Comment: @AdamKatz in that case you should not send the user back to the home screen according to Design guidelines.

Comment: @Adam Do you want to open specific activity from Gallery?

Comment: Read "Navigation Between Apps"  https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#between-apps

Comment: thanks that was really helpful the navigation between apps, i brought it up with our ux engineer and they said they want to keep users in the app so we are going to go against material design here :(

Comment: ive updated the question let me know if you understand better now